# What is a wrapping conversion?

Tags: c#, casting

When you try to cast a value from a type to another incompatible type, you get the following error in C#:

> CS0039 Cannot convert type A to B via reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion

I understand how to potentially fix this, but my question is about the types of conversions themselves. It mentions reference (superclass to subclass or vice versa), boxing and unboxing (value type to object) and null type (e.g. int to int?) conversions, but then what is a wrapping conversion? This one isn't obvious to me, and searching for this term just brings back results about error CS0039, instead of an explanation of the concept.

Comment: @Alex: That's just a user-defined conversion operator, which cannot be used with `as`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wrapping converts a non-nullable value type to its nullable equivalent. Unwrapping is the reverse. For example:

```
int x = 5;
int? y = x; // Wrapping
int z = (int) y; // Unwrapping
```

The C# spec doesn't actually call these "wrapping conversions" and "unwrapping conversions" but it does talk about wrapping and unwrapping. From section 4.1.10 of the C# 5 spec, or the [online spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#nullable-types) (emphasis mine):

> An instance for which `HasValue` is false is said to be null. A null instance has an undefined value. Attempting to read the `Value` of a null instance causes a `System.InvalidOperationException` to be thrown. The process of accessing the `Value` property of a nullable instance is referred to as **unwrapping**.
>   In addition to the default constructor, every nullable type `T?` has a public constructor that takes a single argument of type `T`. Given a value `x` of type `T`, a constructor invocation of the form
>
> ```
> new T?(x)
> ```
>
> creates a non-null instance of `T?` for which the `Value` property is `x`. The process of creating a non-null instance of a nullable type for a given value is referred to as **wrapping**.

Comment: [Free link to the spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#nullable-types) where this is mentioned.

Comment: To add to this, this is what Arturo mistakenly assumed to be »null type conversion«, which I think refers to converting the `null` literal to any compatible type instead.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Thanks, was just adding the quote too. Will add a link... although that's currently the draft C# 6 spec, the URL suggests it will always be "current".

Comment: @Joey: the error message could use some work, really. "null type conversion" is not in the spec either. That may or may not mean "null literal conversion"; it may also be referring to some other conversion of nullables not covered by "wrapping". The compiler ought to stick to the [terminology established by the spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions).

Comment: @JeroenMostert:  The "null type" used to be in the spec but Mads and I removed it as it was unnecessary. Apparently I forgot to update the error message when we did.

Comment: @EricLippert: I bet some really obscure but incredibly important piece of software run by a Fortune 500 company will break if you do it now because it's matching on the text... but hey, at least we now know what's what. :-)

Comment: So "null type" and "nullable type" are not the same thing. I see. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 4):

As stated in [the spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions):

> If the nullable conversion is from `S` to `T?`, the conversion is
>   evaluated as the underlying conversion from `S` to `T` **followed by a
>   wrapping from `T` to `T?`**.

Which implicitly means that wrapping means to turn a non-nullable into it's nullable type variant.