# C# (CS0039) How to define conversion to a custom class from a string, with the `as` operator?

Tags: c#, casting

Is is possible to define (perhaps) an operator for a class which could enable using 'as' conversion?

The point is:

```
class C
{
   string a;
   string b;

   public C what_here(string s)
   {
      a = s.Substring(0, 2);
      b = s.Substring(3);
   }
}
```

The class' use:

```
("something" as C).a;
```

This gives:

> Error CS0039: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'C' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion

P.S. the true `class C` is much bigger, the point is just how to enable the `as`
operator, which I just got used to...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a wrapping conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49013273/what-is-a-wrapping-conversion)

Comment: look up operator overloading such as implicit or explicit casts

Comment: See [Conversion operators (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/conversion-operators)

Comment: Cant you use a constructor and pass the string as an argument rather than cast it?
`new C("Something").a`. I Suppose my question to you is, why do you need to cast the object?

Comment: FYI: With regard to reference types/classes, boxing/unboxing cannot be "enabled" as boxing/unboxing simply doesn't make sense with reference types. (Boxing/unboxing is what happens to values of _value_ types if they need to be passed as reference, like `int a = 5; object o = a; int b = (int) o;`)

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/as) for `as`:

> Note that the as operator performs only reference conversions, nullable conversions, and boxing conversions. The as operator can't perform other conversions, such as user-defined conversions, which should instead be performed by using cast expressions.

So you won't be able to use `as` to invoke an implicit operator.

However, if you're prepared to use implicit or explicit casting:

```
class C
{
   // Obviously you want to encapsulate these as properties, not fields
   public string a;
   public string b;

   public static implicit operator C(string s)
   {
      var localA = s.Substring(0, 2);
      var localB = s.Substring(3);
      return new C
      {
         a = localA,
         b = localB
      };
   }
}

void Main()
{
    C myC = "AA BBBBBBBB"; // Or explicitly, var myC = (C)"AA BBBBBBBB"
    Console.WriteLine(myC.a);
    Console.WriteLine(myC.b);
}
```

**Output:**

```
AA
BBBBBBBB
```

**But! Don't abuse the conversion operators**

As per @Kieran's comment, conversion operators, when used in arbitrary ways, can be really difficult for others to read. It's not particularly intuitive that a string should *automagically* be converted into your own custom class. IMO the following alternatives are easier to read.

A constructor overload:

```
var myC = new C("string to parse here");
```

or an extension method:

```
var myC = "string to parse here".ToC();
```

where `ToC` will be the same code as the conversion operator, but with the signature `public static C ToC(this string s)`.

Comment: Thanks, I was just 'hoping' there is a way to somehow omit the true and allow as operator to 'use' the implicit conversion... :(

Comment: From a readability point of view, the 'magic' of conversion operators can often make the code hard for others to follow. To be honest, I would make the conversion more explicit, either via construction, or via method (e.g. extension)