# Unable to cast object of type ‘System.String’ to type ‘AuthBotES.ReturnIntents’

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service

Currently I had integrate LUIS with Bot Framework v4.

When I search for result match with Intent,

the Bot return me with this Error:

**Error : Unable to cast object of type ‘System.String’ to type ‘AuthBotES.ReturnIntents’.**

[image]
My Source code as below:

```
   if (stepContext.Result != null)
            {
                var result = (ReturnIntents)stepContext.Result;

            var msg = $"{result}";
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(msg), cancellationToken);
            }
```

and my ReturnIntents classes.

```
  public class ReturnIntents
    {
        public string Intent { get; set; }
        public double Score { get; set; }
        public string Entities { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What template/sample are you using? It would be good if you could include some more detail.

Comment: @MattStannett I'm using this sample https://github.com/cheahengsoon/LUISBotv4/blob/master/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs

Comment: I have added an edit at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

A few issues here:

1. The first code block you posted looks to be for handling the result of a dialog, *not* for processing a LUIS result.
2. The cast from `string` to `ReturnIntents` will always fail.
3. Even if your cast of `stepContext.Result` to `ReturnIntents` did work, your `msg` variable would only contain `namespace.to.class.ReturnIntents` (the string representation of the object type, *not* the string representation of the objects properties.
4. Your `msg` variable is redundant.

I will address these in the order that they occur.

---

**1 - Incorrect code block**

This block of code looks suspiciously like code used to [process a dialog](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/a0491c8bd15c392bcd0641f820eb3215538a7ca7/templates/Customer-Support-Template/CustomerSupportTemplate/Dialogs/Orders/CancelOrderDialog.cs#L75) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/43.complex-dialog/Dialogs/ReviewSelectionDialog.cs#L87) e.g.:

```
var result = (bool)stepContext.Result;
```

Rather than the code for [handling a LUIS result](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/14.nlp-with-dispatch/Bots/DispatchBot.cs#L29) e.g.:

```
var dispatchResult = await cognitiveModels.DispatchService.RecognizeAsync(dc.Context, CancellationToken.None);
```

---

**2 - Casting error**

The error is telling you that it doesn't know how to convert a `string` object to a `ReturnIntents` object. To convert the string to your object you could use a couple of methods:

1. Use the `NewtonSoft.Json` NuGet package to allow you to turn the JSON string into your object as explained [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm).
   2) A user defined type conversion as detailed in the official docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/conversion-operators) and explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55048630/5209435).

**This error is a red herring in terms of your solution because I believe you're accidentally copied in the wrong block of code.**

---

**3 - Incorrect ToString behaviour**

To get the string value of a `ReturnIntents` you will need to [override the ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method) method for the class and write your own custom implementation.

---

**4 - Redundant cast**

This:

```
// We know that this cast fails, and that stepContext.Result is a string
var result = (ReturnIntents)stepContext.Result;

// This will only return <namespace.path>.ReturnIntents (if the cast above works)
var msg = $"{result}";

// Passing in message msg isn't required, we can just pass in stepContext.Result
await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(msg), cancellationToken);
```

Becomes:

```
var result = stepContext.Result;

await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(result), cancellationToken);
```

---

So what I actually think you actually want is the following:

```
var dispatchResult = await cognitiveModels.DispatchService.RecognizeAsync<ReturnIntents>(dc.Context, CancellationToken.None);
```

Which will send the user's input off to LUIS, and deserialize the response into a `ReturnIntents` object.

---

**Edit to provide solution to the OP**

The `ExecuteLuisQuery` method called [here](https://github.com/cheahengsoon/LUISBotv4/blob/master/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs#L61), and defined [here](https://github.com/cheahengsoon/LUISBotv4/blob/master/LuisHelper.cs#L17) returns a `ReturnIntents` object.

This object is passed as an `option` to the `ReturnIntentDialog` [here](https://github.com/cheahengsoon/LUISBotv4/blob/master/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs#L75). Because this comes through as an instance of the `object` type you have a few options inside your `FinalStepAsync` method [here](https://github.com/cheahengsoon/LUISBotv4/blob/master/Dialogs/ReturnIntentDialog.cs#L28) to turn your options object into a `ReturnIntents` object.:

1. Casting

```
ReturnIntents returnIntents = null;

if (stepContext.Options is ReturnIntents)
{
    returnIntents = (ReturnIntents)stepContext.Options;
}
```

2. Deserializing

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

ReturnIntents returnIntents = null;

if (stepContext.Options is ReturnIntents)
{
    returnIntents = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReturnIntents>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stepContext.Options));
}
```